# App to video chat between iPod Touch 4 and Android phone?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, software-recommendation, android, chat

I am looking to do a video chat between an iPod Touch 4 and an Android phone (not sure which version, but less than a year old).  Both of these devices have video cameras and microphones, I'm just not sure the easiest way to video chat between the two.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo! Messenger, Skype or Fring should do.

Answer (score 0):

[Tango](http://tango.me/) will also work.